# How to Implement org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.semanticHighlighting

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to implement content-assist and some custom highlighting as a plugin for Eclipse, after a lot of research I found this eclipse [document](http://wiki.eclipse.org/New_Help_for_Old_Friends_V).

I got content-assist working for XML documents, the problem is the part about `SemanticHighlighting`, I didn't find any information about how to implement this extension-point and I'm a bit lost. The only info that I found is the XSD for the extension point.

I'm trying to make some customs expressions on XML get a different color Ex:

```
<span>%%colored_text%%</span>
```

Where can I get more information about this org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.semanticHighlighting and how to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a lot of a documentation on the semantic highlighting for SSE. The document that you found is a little light on details. For an example, the XSL project implemented [semantic highlighting](https://bugs.eclipse.org/256339) using the extension point.

The basic idea behind the semantic highlighting extension point is that when a change occurs, implementors will be asked if it can 'consume' a region of the document. If it can, it will return an array of Positions that can be highlighted by that particular highlighter. It can apply only one style, so it ends up being very specific. For example, you wouldn't be able to say 'color this part of the region blue and this other part of the region red'. You would need two separate highlighters to accomplish that.

The highlighter obtains style information for the highlight by using a preference store that you return from `getPreferenceStore()`. You'll then need to set up keys that the highlighter will use to look up styles from that preference store. If you use the `styleStringKey` on the extension point, the only key of importance from the semantic highlighting implementation is the one returned from `getEnabledPreferenceKey()`. This is kind of the condensed way to declare a style, as it only takes 2 preferences to get going. The semantic highlighting framework knows how the parse the string value returned by the preference store for the `styleStringKey` into the appropriate style components. Just follow the format as defined on the New Help for Old Friends document that you linked to.

Now, if you want to keep all the style components separate, the other get*PreferenceKey() methods become important. You'll have to define keys for each of them, and then add default values for each of those keys in your preference initializer.

[org.eclipse.wst.xsl.ui.internal.preferences.XSLUIPreferenceInitializer](http://git.eclipse.org/c/sourceediting/webtools.sourceediting.xsl.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.wst.xsl.ui/src/org/eclipse/wst/xsl/ui/internal/preferences/XSLUIPreferenceInitializer.java) has examples of both ways to define these style defaults.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the help Nsand, after this explanation I got it working! The only problem is that I didn't get the styleStringKey working though. Maybe I was using the syntax wrongly: #FF0000 | #FF0000 | true | true | true | true. I tryied with names too: RGB foreground #FF0000 | RGB background #FF0000 | bold true | italic true | strikethrough true | underline true. Stil didn't worked. But I can live with the PreferencesStore anyway. Thanks!

Comment: @IsraelFonseca For the styleStringKey, you still need to use the preference store and provide that from your semantic highlighting implementation. As an example, you would have `styleStringKey="my.style"` in your extension. Then in your preference initializer, you would have `preferenceStore.setDefault("my.style", "#ff0000 | null | true")` to make something bold and red with no background.

Comment: Oh, so simple! I got it wrong before. Thanks again! I'll play with that IStructuredDocumentRegion now, thank you very much!

Comment: One last comment nsand, after finally doing the implementation, I noticed that the highlighting apply is a bit slow (you can write an "unhilighted" sentence before the highlight actually get applied). Is it normal?

Comment: And if possible, do you know where is the repository of the extension? If it's opensource I would want to contribute!

Comment: @IsraelFonseca yes, that's normal. The semantic highlighting waits for user input to quiet down before it does its work. [webtools.sourceediting](http://git.eclipse.org/gitroot/sourceediting/webtools.sourceediting.git) is the git repository and bugs/features can be opened through [bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=WTP%20Source%20Editing)